# Magento 1 / 2 and Varnish

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, varnish

I currently run Magento 1 on my prod server without Varnish - it runs Amasty's FPC.
I have moved my Mage 2 dev env. to my prod server now and want to use Varnish.

My question - can I install Varnish and configure it on the server and then only use it for Mage 2, while I'm in my testing phase?

So I can leave Magento 1 as it is without any Varnish configurations.
But I can enable Varnish on Magento 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely possible. As long as the Magento 1 & 2 stores are identified by a different hostname or URL, you can match the Magento 1 URL in the VCL code and bypass the cache.

Here's an example where the Magento 1 store is hosted on the `mage1.com` domain:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Host == "mage1.com") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

The only thing that might cause some difficulties is the health checking. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/#fixing-the-backend-health-checks-for-magento-24.

This may result in defining 2 backends, each witha separate backend definition:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend mage1 {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

backend mage2 {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Host == "mage1.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = mage1;
        return(pass);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = mage2;
    }
}
```

> FYI: these VCL snippets can be prepended to the full Magento VCL logic to make sure that the cache is bypassed for the Magento 1 store before the caching logic kicks in that is intended for the Magento 2 store.

I recommend that you read the full tutorial we created about Varnish & Magento: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/